# How to duplicate MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE event to children

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have ViewGroup implementation, but it works as a component, not a container. Okay, when user scrolls control it should scroll ***all*** its children in different direction.

So interaction scheme is:

```
              ||    MotionEvent
              \/    

          My Control
             /|\
            / | \
           /  |  \ message clones
          /   |   \
     Child1  Ch2  Child3
```

How can I implement that scheme?

Unworked variant:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    boolean intercepted = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);

        if (child instanceof ViewGroup ) {

            intercepted |= ((ViewGroup) child).onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) || intercepted;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    boolean intercepted = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        intercepted |= child.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev) || intercepted;
}
```

That variant also doesn't work:

```
private void dispatchTouch(MotionEvent ev) {
    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++){
        getChildAt(i).dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: i do not understand your question if you explain it in more details i think it gets better btw where is your scroll listener.

Comment: @mmlooloo, I do not have scroll listeners. I have some child views and I need they could receive ACTION_MOVE messages of his parent.

Child view - it's not necessary ScrollView. It might be just any custom view that doesn't have scroll listeners.